# Android app quits without exception while restoring network on emulator

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am using BroadcastReceiver to listen to network connection changes. I register my receiver through AndroidManifest.xml file. When my emulator changes its state from 'Disconnected' to 'Connected' the OnReceiver() function of the BroadcastReceiver is called. But when the network status changes from 'Connected' to 'Disconnected' my application quits with no errors or logs or exception. Just the message that 'Unfortunately App has stopped working'. This message is shown on the emulator and no exceptions or errors in the LogCat window.

The receiver is registered in the xml file as

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.jumbybay.common.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

The last thing I see in my LogCat is the following

```
09-14 00:09:11.691: D/Tethering(149): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
09-14 00:09:47.991: D/ConnectivityService(149): ConnectivityChange for mobile: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED
09-14 00:09:47.991: D/ConnectivityService(149): Attempting to switch to wifi
09-14 00:09:48.141: D/ConnectivityService(149): resetConnections(eth0, 3)
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't get actual stacktrace, do you?